# run hook if condition with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, delayed-job

I have this job on my controller:

```
def action1
 #code here
  order = Order.find(params[:id])
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(ExpiredMessage.new(order), 2, 2.days.from_now)
 #code here
end
```

I have inside `myapp/app/jobs` a custom job inside a file called `expired_message.rb` with the  next content:

```
class ExpiredMessage < Struct.new(:order)
 def perform
  #code to run here for example order.save
   order.any_method
 end
end
```

I want execute the code inside `perform method` only `if order.status ==  "PA"`

**How can I run a hook before save the order to check `if order.status ==  "PA"` on my custom job?**

**Otherwise, if the order.status != "PA" I want delete the job before this job is executed.**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't check it before adding it to the queue?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that the order status can change to other status inside the time 2.minutes or 2.days...etc

Comment: How can other processes access this order object to modify it?  Or do you mean changed in the database?  If so, what is the purpose of 'saving' it - it's there already!

Comment: Order.save is a example of code. I have changed the code if leads to confusion. After created a new order I want run `order.any_method` after 2 days but only `if order.status == "PA"` on my database. If after create order the `order.status` is different to `"PA"`. I don't want `order.any_method`. I do not know if I have explained correctly

Comment: Then a simple `if` condition with a db reload should suffice - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check an object's status from the database - call `reload` on it.  Otherwise, just check it as you would any other object:

```
def perform
  order.any_method if order.reload.status == "PA"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your response is correct. The problem was on reload db :D. Thank you!